# MVC EditorFor TimeSpan.Hours not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, timespan

I have model with a TimeSpan (TimeWorked), I want to bind a text box to the Hours and Minutes fields of the TimeSpan.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeWorked.Hours)
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeWorked.Minutes)
```

But in the controller post method the values are not part of the posted model because `TimeSpan.Hours` and `TimeSpan.Minutes` have no setter methods.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I am bit not clear. Are you having problem generating textbox or your concern is about model binding?

Comment: Either create properties in your model or create arguments in your post action method for hours and minutes, create TimeSpan  and assign to Model.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana I know I can add an pass the Hours and Minutes in via the post args or by adding them to the Model, but I'd like a "neater" way of doing it. I've read a bit about editor templates, but have not found enough information

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps:

### Model Class

```
 public class TestModel
  {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeWorked { get; set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        TimeWorked = new TimeSpan(3, 20, 0);
        name = "hello";
    }
}
```

### Custom ModelBinder

```
 public class TimeModelBinder:DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (TestModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        var Hour = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["TimeWorked.Hours"];
        var minutes = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["TimeWorked.Minutes"];
        var time = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(Hour), int.Parse(minutes), 0);

        model.TimeWorked = time;
        return model;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(TimeModelBinder))]TestModel _model)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is TimeSpan doesn't have a parameterless contrustor and the default model binder cannot create a new instance of it, you may need to define a model binder for TimeSpan, something like this https://gist.github.com/chaoaretasty/1671586

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a custom modelbinder for `TimeSpan?` based on a version I had previously found. It's a bit long to paste straight in here but I have put up as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaoaretasty/1671586)